# How to send push notification when data changes from API

Tags: swift, firebase, api, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm currently creating an iOS application in Swift that fetches data from a third party API and then displaying it on the screen.

One of the features includes enabling push notification so that the user gets a push notification if there's a change in the API data.

However, I'm struggling to figure out how to implement the push notification side of it so that I can constantly monitor the API data and then send out a push notification when there's a change in the data.

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to do this? I've previously used Firebase to implement push notifications but the push was triggered from a user action. I was wondering whether there's something similar I can utilise in Firebase or if there's any other recommendations?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to use cloud functions. If you're monitoring the data client side you can perhaps make a call to a cloud function to send a push notification.

Or you may want to look into local notifications.  I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish so it's tough to really say, but as far as a direction goes I would recommend checking out [cloud functions](https://medium.com/@jerinamathews/send-firebase-cloud-messaging-fcm-to-a-topic-using-cloud-function-when-realtime-database-value-fa78fa758549) and [local notifications](https://medium.com/@jonathan2457/location-triggered-notifications-on-ios-24033919fb9a) to see if either one solves your needs.

Edit:

Now that I know more what you're looking for I would check out this article [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/updating_your_app_with_background_app_refresh).  It will explain about Background App Refresh.  Here's an excerpt from the article.

> When the system calls your app delegate’s application(_:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:) method, configure a URLSession object to download any new data. The system waits until network and power conditions are good, so you should be able to retrieve adequate amounts of data quickly. When you finish updating your app, call the completion handler and provide an accurate result of your outcome, which can include saying that no new data was available.

So in the application(_:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:) method you would want to:

1. Download the new data
2. Compare it to old data and see if there's been a change
3. And then probably I would just display a Local Notification to the user.

I think that would be the easiest way with your current architecture and without having to write any server side code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Sorry I should've made it clearer. In a nutshell, currently have an application that fetches the weather data from a third party API when I open the app. What I want to achieve is so that if the app is not running, to be able to automatically send a push notification to the user if there's a change in the API data (I.e. if the weather changes for example). But I'm not sure how I can constantly monitor the API data when the app is not running, and then call a function off the back of it.

Comment: Thanks - that sounds like a good solution, will give that a try :)